# How to create node navigation to cycle through nodes of specific content type

Tags: navigation

I would like to add node navigations (prev - next) at the bottom of each node of a specific content type so that I can cycle through all the nodes for that content type.
Here is an example (scroll to the bottom of the article) http://happycog.com/work/blackhills.  You'll notice that there are navigation links that take you to the previous or next article.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how I can accomplish this.  I've looked at various contrib modules but none have given me the result I am looking for.

Thank you,

mario

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these two modules:

- [Flippy](https://www.drupal.org/project/flippy)
- [Custom Pagers](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_pagers)

Custom Pagers is more versatile, but I found it buggy.

Another solution, more custom and flexible, would be creating a custom field in the content type (via [hook_field_extra_fields()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7) or [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)), and creating a custom query to get the next/previous node ids. If you prefer to go with the custom way but don't want to add a custom field, you can just preprocess the node and add the variable in your .tpl file.

[Previous/Next API](https://www.drupal.org/project/prev_next) module could be used to get the node ids without the need to create the query yourself, apparently making the solution more scalable. It's still a -dev version though.

Comment: I've used [Previous/Next API](https://www.drupal.org/project/prev_next) for this in the past, but it's still dev.